# update global variable with click event in js

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, state

I am beginner with JS.

I want to update global variable with click event, But I don't know how;

for example:

```
let a = 0;

example.addEventListener('click', () => {
a = 1;
console.log(a);
})
```

this prints

> a = 1:

But i don't want to update it only in function, i want to update globally like below:

```
let a = 0;

example.addEventListener('click',() => {
a = 1;
})

console.log(a)
```

This still logs

> a = 0

even it's clicked , But why? How can I update it globally with click event?

Comment: You are updating only when you click but you `log` value of `a` before. Because `callback` function to `addEventListener` will only trigger after user `click`

Comment: Thank you, Now I understand why this happens but how can I solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you run your code `console.log(a)` will not wait for the click event and hence it will log the current value of *a* which is 0, and it will not run again after firing the click event. You did not update it only in function but you just don't have anything to show you the updated value, instead you can do something like this:

```
let a = 0;
example.addEventListener('click',() => {
a = 1;
checkValue();
})

function checkValue() {
  console.log(a)
}
```

Comment: But in this case, it will be like in the first example. It will be changed only in the click function and not globally. I want something like a state in React.js. when you change the state in React.js the value changes everywhere. I appreciate your help.

Comment: it did change everywhere but you only didn't *see* that. so in order to see that you should log the value after the click event not before.

Answer (score 0):

By default in js there is hoisting in which where ever the global variable is declare it will go to the top of the file in js.

```js
let a = 0;
example.addEventListener('click',() => {
a = 1;
checkValue();
})

function checkValue() {
  console.log(a)
}
```